# Browser is done loading and capybara still failing test

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, automation, capybara

I am running automation that checks `document.readyState === 'complete'` and also a local variable called `window.renderComplete` (for when the server is done with rendering the page).

But somehow the `Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.title` is failing a `title == Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.title` for a few loops of that check. It probably loops 10 times before the check passes and it breaks the loop.

Is there a time period after the browser gets all the data that it takes to set the data into certain variables? Or is this a capybara flaw? I can't really pinpoint why there would still be a delay in the browser, if readyState and renderComplete are both true.

```
renderComplete = page.evaluate_script("(window.renderComplete == true) && (document.readyState === 'complete');")

      if renderComplete
        puts "pass 1"
      else
        loop do
          renderComplete = page.evaluate_script("window.renderComplete == true;")
          break if renderComplete == true
        end
        puts "pass 2"
      end

browser = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser
Timeout::timeout(Capybara.default_max_wait_time) do
    i=1
    loop do
      puts "loop! #{i}"
      i+=1
      break if title == browser.title
    end
  end
assert_equal title, browser.title
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear from your question what exactly you're doing (maybe show the actual code in your question), however you shouldn't really be calling driver specific methods, or doing direct == comparison on `title` - you should just use the `have_title`/`assert_title`/`has_title?` methods depending on exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @thomaswalpole Thanks for the comment. I added some code that simplifies what I am doing. So basically the first loop passes and it actually outputs "pass 1", but then it fails the assert_equal at the bottom so I added another loop before it. That loops about 10-20 times before it breaks, then it passes the assert_equal. This tells me that the first loop isn't checking something and the browser is still in fact 'loading'

Comment: What is the variable `title` in that?

Comment: @thomaswalpole its an expected string passed in from the def header like this
check_title_and_path_for_ng2(title, path)

Comment: Ok - then you should just be doing something like   `page.assert_title(title)`.  Also using `Timeout::timeout` with tasks involving network communication is dangerous since the connection can be left in an unknown/broken state (basically `Timeout::timeout` itself is pretty broken - see http://www.mikeperham.com/2015/05/08/timeout-rubys-most-dangerous-api/)

Comment: @thomaswalpole you are a genius. I forgot that it is expected, so just checking the page for the title is the test. You do not need to check it with assert_equal and also assert_title has implicit waits

Comment: Added as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing equal assertions against `title`, nor using driver specific methods (anytime you do `current_session.driver.xxx` you're probably doing something wrong. To verify a pages title is what you expect just use one of the title assertion/matcher methods provided by Capybara (which will also include the builtin waiting/retrying)

```
page.assert_title(expected_title)
```

Also, note that using `Timeout::timeout` with code that's talking to network clients is highly dangerous since it can interrupt code at any point and leave those communications in a non-recoverable state.  If you need to use some sort of timeout with Capybara you're much better off just sleeping in a loop and checking the condition until the expected time has passed than using `Timeout::timeout` - see http://www.mikeperham.com/2015/05/08/timeout-rubys-most-dangerous-api/